Problem with csvsimple and csvrerader. Not every Data type gets show
Here is my code:
\begin{filecontents*}{DateTime.csv}
Gruppe;Date;Time
Gruppe 1;27.05.2024;13:00
Gruppe 2;28.05.2024;18:00
Gruppe 3;29.05.2024;21:00
Gruppe 4;30.05.2024;12:00
Gruppe 5;27.09.2024;22:00
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{Group.csv}
Gruppe ;;Name;Lastname;;;;;;;;number1;number2;number3
Gruppe 1;;Tim1;Drof;;;;;;;;12;23;34
Gruppe 2;;Tim2;Drof;;;;;;;;12;23;34
Gruppe 2;;Tim21;Drof;;;;;;;;12;23;34
Gruppe 4;;Tim3;Drof;;;;;;;;12;23;34
Gruppe 3;;Tim3;Drof;;;;;;;;12;23;34
Gruppe 5;;Tim5;Drof;;;;;;;;12;23;34
Gruppe 5;;Tim5;Drof;;;;;;;;12;23;34

\end{filecontents*}





\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{ifthen} % Paket für bedingte Anweisungen
\usepackage{xstring} % Paket für Zeichenkettenmanipulation
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%achten das in Spalte k (11) in der Orginal CSV Datei keine Semikolona verwendet werden
\csvstyle{mystyle}{
    tabular=|c|c|c|c|c|p{7cm}|,
    table head=\toprule Name & Lastname & number1 & number2 & number3 & Unterschrift \\ \midrule,
        table foot=\bottomrule,
    no head,
    late after line=\\\hline,
        late after last line=\\,
}
\csvstyle{Date}{
    tabular=ccc,
    table head= Date & Time &,
        no head,
    late after last line=\\,
}
\title{Title}

%\newcommand{\csvfilename}{Gruppenliste_Labor_Flugversuchslabor.csv} %Name CSV. Datei

%\newcommand{\DatumUhrzeitGruppe 1}{27.05.2024;13:00}
%\newcommand{\DatumUhrzeitGruppe 2}{27.05.2024;14:00}
%\newcommand{\DatumUhrzeitGruppe 3}{27.05.2024;15:00}

\newcounter{Gruppe}
\setcounter{Gruppe}{1} %Ausgabe dieses counters über \Arabic{Gruppe} --> Nutzen für Abfrage ob Gruppe 1,2,3 etc in der Zeile steht
\newcounter{Abbruch}
%\setcounter{Abbruch}{0}

\newcounter{test}
\setcounter{test}{1}

\newcounter{MaxGruppe}

\newcounter{Tabelle}
\setcounter{Tabelle}{0}


\begin{document}
% Anzahl der Zeilen in Ihrer CSV-Datei und setzen Sie den Zähler Abbruch entsprechend
\csvreader[separator=semicolon, late after line={\stepcounter{Abbruch}}]{Group.csv}{}{}
%Ausgabe Abbruch zur Überprüfung
%Abbruch: \arabic{Abbruch}

%Schleife zur Bestimmung GruppenAnzahl
    \whiledo{\value{test} < \value{Abbruch}}
    {
        \csvreader[separator=semicolon,]{Group.csv}{}{
        \ifcsvstrcmp{\csvcoli}{Gruppe \arabic{Gruppe}}
        {
                \StrBehind{\csvcoli}{Gruppe }[\tempnum]% Zahl hinter Gruppe in \tempnum speichern
        }
        {
            
        }
        }
        \stepcounter{Gruppe}
        \stepcounter{test}
    }
\setcounter{MaxGruppe}{\tempnum}%counter MaxGruppe den Wert von \tempnum übertragen
    %Ausgabe Max. Gruppenanzahl
    Gruppenanzahl: \arabic{MaxGruppe} 
    
    
% Grppe counter auf reset
\setcounter{Gruppe}{1}
    % Schleife ausgabe der Tabelle für jede Gruppe
\whiledo{\value{Tabelle} < \value{MaxGruppe}} %Anzahl der Gruppen +1
    {%
        \begin{landscape}
        %Mit Ihrer Unterschrift bestätigen Sie die Anwesenheit zum Flugversuch\\\\
        \begin{table}
        \csvreader[Date,separator=semicolon,
                            ]{DateTime.csv}{}{
        \ifcsvstrcmp{\csvcoli}{Gruppe \arabic{Gruppe}}
        {
            \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & 
            
        }
        {
            %\stpecounter{Abbruch}
             %Noch was hinzufügen, wenn Gruppe nicht gefunden wurde?
        }}
        \end{table}
        
        
        \begin{table}[htb]
        \centering
        \caption{\textbf{Gruppe \arabic{Gruppe}\\
        %\csname \DatumUhrzeitGruppe \arabic{Gruppe} \endcsname
        }
        }
        \adjustbox{max width=\linewidth}{
        \csvreader[mystyle, separator=semicolon,
                            filter equal={\csvcoli}{Gruppe \arabic{Gruppe}}]{Group.csv}{}{
        \ifcsvstrcmp{\csvcoli}{Gruppe \arabic{Gruppe}}
        {
            \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv & \csvcolxii & \csvcolxiv & \csvcolxiii &\\
            
        }
        {
            %\stpecounter{Abbruch}
             %Noch was hinzufügen, wenn Gruppe nicht gefunden wurde?
        }
        }}
        \end{table}
        \end{landscape}
        \stepcounter{Gruppe}
        \stepcounter{Tabelle}
    }
    
    
    
    
\end{document}


My Problem now is that the Data from "DateTime.csv" only gets shown for cetain Groups as you can see in the left hand cornor of the following pictures:

Can somoene please explain to me why that happened and how I can fix this?
Thanks a lot in advance for your time and help.
Best regards Roman

You really should not combine boobtabs with vertical lines. Either use booktabs or use vertical lines, but not both.

You use two CSV files in your document. You supply only one and it has a name that is different from those two. Probably DateTime.csv=DatumUhrzeit.csv, but then the other one is still missing. Please make it compilable without errors.

Figured out the Problem! I tried to change tha Dates in
\begin{filecontents*}{DateTime.csv}
Gruppe;Date;Time
Gruppe 1;27.05.2024;13:00
Gruppe 2;28.05.2024;18:00
Gruppe 3;29.05.2024;21:00
Gruppe 4;30.05.2024;12:00
Gruppe 5;27.09.2024;22:00
\end{filecontents*}

That was wrong. While compiling a csv file is genereted and stoced on your computer which you can change.
